# Motherboard replaced, Windows 7 fails to start; how to copy drivers over?

Tags: windows, drivers, motherboard, sysprep, system-recovery

I recently replaced the motherboard for a Windows 7 system and even in safe mode boot it crashes right when it loads `classpnp.sys`.

Do I need to some way manually copy the driver files over to the hard drive so the system will boot?

### EDIT:

I re-installed 7 over the old 7. If I copy `system32` and `SysWOW64` over with the driver dirs would the old system boot up? I have it cloned off with AOMEI so I could restore it with AOMEI then copy the driver dirs over from the re-intall

Comment: Did you prepare Windows to be booted on the new hardware before you replaced the motherboard?

Comment: No. I placed the new motherboard in and then booted the drive since the old motherboard broke

Comment: Well that won't work.  You need to Sysprep the installation.

Comment: Is there a way to proceed from here?

Comment: If you had as working installation there would be. I suggest pulling personal documents and reinstalling Windows

Comment: Riddle me this. Could I use acronis to in some way clone the drive and have it prep it for a reinstall to the current system?

Comment: Why not do a reinstall?

Comment: Trying to preserve installed applications ect... theres a lot there.

Comment: I would highly suggest you listen to Gaurav and Ramhound, Trying to keep software perserved on a new OS install is a pure nightmare. It's a pain in the butt, BUT you should make a list of all the software you installed, and reinstall everything fresh. There are alot of hardcore pc users that reinstall an OS because of all the software they installed, to get a "fresh start" take advantage of that, and get rid of all the non-sense software you don't need anymore.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In recovery mode the drive letters may change find out which one has the **WINDOWS** folder and substitue this drive letter for **C:**

try this boot from win 7 DVD. Repair->command prompt

```
 Download chipset drivers and AHCI and/or IDE
 Extract them onto a USB stick into a folder name Drivers

 DISM.exe /Image:C:\ /Add-Driver /Driver:d:\Drivers\ /Recurse

In our example the D: is the USB stick and you have your extracted drivers in the drivers folder.
```

Comment: I tried that. However, I only got a second further in. My mother board is a ASROCK 960GC-GS FX. That command found 16 driver files I think and that is how I got a littler further. If the drivers are in the MSI or EXE files I don't have a way to get to them ;/

Comment: Yes, you do!! 7zip from 7zip.org will open a **MSI** file.